# Copy Maven pom.xml with version change

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

Sorry for the long post, but I first have to explain our setup:

### Setup

We produce some *core* jars that are used in multiple other projects that are actually released. Right now, many of our projects use Ant with Ivy. In fact, all of the *core* projects were strictly Ant with Ivy.

- In our `ivy.xml` files, the version number is a property. This property is set universally because the developers didn't update this property when we went to a new release. This keeps all of our projects (including *core* jars) on the same version number.
- We release our jars as Maven jars. We do this via the Ivy `<ivy:makepom>` task. When this task is used, the version number is automatically substituted for the property.
- We also embed this `pom.xml` into our jars like Maven does.
- We also create a second POM called `pom-snapshot.xml`. This is the same as the `pom.xml`, but it has `-SNAPSHOT` after the version number.

When Jenkins does a build, it automatically deploys the jar to our Snapshot repository. It uses `mvn deploy:deploy-file` and the `pom-snapshot.xml` file. This allows developers to try the jar before it's officially released.

When the developer is satisfied with the jar, they can promote that jar to our Maven Release repository. This uses the Jenkins *promote* plugin, the `pom.xml`, and `mvn deploy:deploy-file`.

### What We Want

We now have a few *core* jar projects that are moving over to Maven. The developers want to keep this same system in place: Each build does a SNAPSHOT deployment to our Maven repo, and then the developer can deploy a selected build to our Maven repo via a Jenkins plugin.

Right now:

- I copy the `pom.xml` under the `target` directory and use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy the jar into our Release repo. This is done by the developer using the *Promote* plugin in Jenkins and not with each build.
- I also copy the `pom.xml` to a `pom-snapshot.xml` file under `target. I use` mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy this to the Snapshot repo after each build.

This works, but I use regular expressions to find the version number of the `pom.xml`, and if I have a `pom.xml` where the Super Pom version (the parent POM) is the same as the version in the `pom.xml`, I end up changing the wrong version.

I was wondering if there's a Maven Plugin that allows you to copy the pom.xml to another directory while changing the version number in the pom itself. Or, is there just a better way to handle this whole issue? I could setup Artifactory to not check version consistency between what I am deploying and the `pom.xml`, but that ended up giving us problems with OSGI projects and with developers not keeping up with the version number.

Answer (score 0):

There is always maven-exec-plugin with which you can do almost anything. But I don't think it is a good idea. Since Maven is always about convention, you should better think of moving to maven-convenient process. With SNAPSHOT versions during development phase and release-prepare/perform to transform SNAPSHOT version into release one.
Check maven-release-plugin [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) It can perform version updates, VCS updates and many more.

Comment: Ah, if things were that easy. Many of our projects are Ant w/ Ivy. We have 50+ projects and 120+ developers -- many of those offshore contractors. We need a centralized approach, and Maven can't provide that. I'll look at the `maven-release-plugin` and the `maven-exec-plugin`.

Comment: @DavidW. I was in the same situation with my current project in july. Except no Ivy. We set up Sonatype Nexus repo, and started to move projects from Ant to Maven one by one. Simple script to copy maven built artifacts from local repo/Nexus into classpath for projects that are still on Ant.

Comment: Bruan When I got here, everything was Ant, sloppy build.xml files, and no dependency management. Jars were checked into SVN and then used. I moved everything to Ivy because it was much easier to modify the existing build.xml to work with Ivy than completely rewriting the builds to work with Maven. However, I wanted all jars to be _Maven compatible_, so we used `<makepom/>` to turn the `ivy.xml` into a `pom.xml`. Now, we're moving new projects to Maven, and I've got to keep everything working.

Comment: I'm using the [maven-version-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to do what I want. Took a bit of hacking, but it's all in our corporate `pom.xml` and out of developer site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [maven-version-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to get what I need. I copy the `pom.xml` to a new directory, run `versions:set` on that `pom.xml`, and then move `pom.xml` to `pom-snapshot.xml` and `pom.xml.versionsBackup` to `pom.xml`.

All of this is inside our parent project `pom.xml` which sets the current version number, Java defaults, site defaults, etc., so the individual projects' pom.xml files are still clean and simple. Everything happens in the background.

I am not happy with the setup, but its compatible with the rest of our projects and their processes, and developers don't have to worry about any of it.